# dhtmlx grid doesnt work properly after loading the grid from cookie and then do hide/show column

Tags: javascript, dhtmlx

we are using dhtmlxgrid library,i need to have the  save and reload features on the grid.So what i am doing currently is save the grid to cookie when saved and then load the grid from cookie when reloaded,as grid.load always load with default configuration i load the  saved cookie into grid in XLE event listener .

everything works fine if i am only persisting hidde/show columns,column order and sorting .but if i persist column size also then  reload works fine but if i check/uncheck columns to show/hide them later then grid is not working properly.

is it how dhtmlxgrid works? or am i doing something wrong?any ideas on how i can persist and reload column sizes as well?

```
grid.saveHiddenColumnsToCookie(name,param)   
grid.saveOrderToCookie(name, param) 
grid.saveSortingToCookie(name,param)    
//grid.saveSizeToCookie(name,param)


grid.loadHiddenColumnsFromCookie(name)   
grid.loadOrderFromCookie(name)   
//grid.loadSizeFromCookie(name) 
grid.loadSortingFromCookie(name)
```

grid doesnt work properly if i enable saving and reloading size as well, in fact reload is happening fine but when i check/uncheck columns to show/hide  coulmns then then grid doesnt work properly and is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try to use the following format and order:

```
grid.saveHiddenColumnsToCookie(name,param)   
grid.saveSortingToCookie(name,param)    
grid.saveSizeToCookie(name,param)
grid.saveOrderToCookie(name, param) 

grid.loadOrderFromCookie(name)   
grid.loadHiddenColumnsFromCookie(name)   
grid.loadSizeFromCookie(name) 
grid.loadSortingFromCookie(name)
```

or the following solution for the autosaving-loading:

```
mygrid.loadOrderFromCookie(name);   
mygrid.loadSizeFromCookie(name);
mygrid.loadHiddenColumnsFromCookie(name);
mygrid.loadSortingFromCookie(name)    

mygrid.enableAutoSizeSaving(name,param);
mygrid.enableAutoHiddenColumnsSaving(name,param);
mygrid.enableSortingSaving(name,param);
mygrid.enableOrderSaving(name,param); 

mygrid.attachEvent("onAfterCMove", function(cInd,posInd){
    mygrid.saveSizeToCookie(name,param);
    mygrid.saveHiddenColumnsToCookie(name,param);
});
```